# GPS send & receive custom data (arduino)

Tags: gps, arduino

I'm working on a school project on which I need to identify a ship model to get its height.
For it, I'd like to use a GPS emitter (because each ship has already one). This emitter should emit an ID that would allow me to get ship' informations into a database.

I don't know how to write custom data in a GPS emission.

Also, I would rather use Arduino.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[GPS](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Global_Positioning_System) is receive-only. It calculates its position according to what it receives.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. But how the websites like http://www.marinetraffic.com/fr/ do to display all ships in realtime ?

Comment: Each ship listens to what their GPS says.  Then they use satellite or radio communications to send a special position report message back to a central point (server, database, etc.).  You could use an Arduino+cell phone+GPS to do the same kind of thing.  The Arduino reads the GPS data, then sends an SMS message to an Android phone, which parses the text and writes something to a database.  Lots of ways to do this...

Comment: Thanks, i saw a lot of tutorials bout SMS+GPS in arduino, but i wanted to find an other way. But if this is the only one, i'll try it.